# Font awesome icons are running perfectly in local but not in production in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome, vercel

In the Next JS font awesome icons are working perfectly on localhost, but when deployed to vercel it's not appearing. I've the separate font css file along with all fonts and linked it in _app.js

**My _app.js file**

```
import "../styles/style.css";
import "../styles/fontawesome.css";
import "../styles/all.min.css";
import "../styles/bootstrap.min.css";
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import "../styles/default.css";
import "../styles/meanmenu.css";
import "../styles/not-logged-responsive.css";
import "../styles/responsive.css";
import "../styles/nprogress.css";
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font-Awesome icon does not show in my ReactJS website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295426/font-awesome-icon-does-not-show-in-my-reactjs-website)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've followed the [official docs](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/use-with) and added `config.autoAddCss = false` and everything.

The next problem can be related to Webpack. Check your `package.json` and see if there's something like

```
"sideEffects": true
// or
"sideEffects": [
   "*.css"
]
```

Font-Awesome icon loading is based on side effects and require something like:

```
"sideEffects": [
   "*.css",
   "your-file-with-fa-imports.js"
]
```

By `your-file-with-fa-imports.js` I mean a file where you have

```
// ^
import {library} from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core"
import {faUser} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"

library.add(faUser)
```

The above lines may vary, respectful to the way you load FA6 icons and how your NextjS is configured. But now you have a direction, at least.